# Use tab view contain another tab

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am trying to create tab, and add another tabs in parent's tab. My problem is when I click child tab, parent close it and when I click any tab, it has to add id to url because my child tab has form and add something. After I add something, trying to return where I was. I guess my problem in style part.

Thanks for help

```css
div.tabs {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
div.tab {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
div.tab:target {
  display: block;
}
:target div.tab {
  display: block;
}
:target div.tab + div.itab {
  display: none;
}
div.tabss {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
div.itab {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
div.itab:target {
  display: block;
}
:target div.itab {
  display: block;
}
:target div.itab + div.itab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<br></br>
<div class="tabbed">
  <!-- Main tab view -->
  <div class="tabs">
    <a href="#aracB">Araç Bilgisi</a>
    <a href="#parcaB">Yedek Parça Bilgisi</a>
    <a href="#musteriB">Müşteri Bilgisi</a>
  </div>

  <div id="aracB" class="tab">
    <p>Araç Bilgisi</p>
  </div>
  <div id="parcaB" class="tab">
    <p>Yedek Parça Bilgisi</p>
    <div class="tabbedd">
      <!-- Chiled tab -->
      <div class="tabss">
        <a href="#yedekE">Yedek Parça Stoğa Ekleme</a>
        <a href="#yedekL">Yedek Parça Stok Listesi</a>
        <a href="#yedekG">Yedek Parça Stok Güncelleme</a>
      </div>
      <div id="yedekE" class="itab">
        <p>Yedek Parça Stoğa Ekleme</p>
        <div w3-include-html="parca_ekle.html"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="yedekL" class="itab">
        <p>Yedek Parça Stok Listesi</p>
        <div w3-include-html="stok_liste.php"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="yedekG" class="itab">
        <p>Yedek Parça Stok Güncelleme</p>
        <div w3-include-html="stok_update.php"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="musteriB" class="tab">
    <p>Müşteri Bilgisi</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All of the js files are boostrap files. I am using basic boostrap starting template from it is website. Btw, I added all code but it won't shown here. Not shown parts are not important as I said all codes are basic template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ (basic template)

Comment: i don see any resemblance  with bootstrap here

Comment: I am new in coding html, bootstrap and css. My friend advice is using the basic template. This is why I write in this way.

Comment: did you even read the bootstrap documentation ? this is not the bootstrap tab syntax